# Center text vertically in a full height child div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to vertically center text inside a child div that is full height, but when I do that it has extra spacing at the bottom. How can I do this without the extra spacing? I'd like to have a nav along with some vertically centered text, but without the extra spacing.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.landing {
  background: url(bg.svg);
  height: 100vh;
}

.landing-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.landing-content h1 {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

.app {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  
  <div class="logo">
     <h1>logo</h1>
  </div>
      
  <div class="landing">
    <div class="landing-content">
      <h1>hi, i'm jordan</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of `height: 100vh` was not suitable, what it does is recognize the view-width as its height and that limit limits the height and recreate a small crack at the bottom. You can try using `height: 100%` instead

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.landing {
  background: url(bg.svg);
  height: 100vh;
}

.landing-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.landing-content h1 {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

.app {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  
  <div class="logo">
     <h1>logo</h1>
  </div>
      
  <div class="landing">
    <div class="landing-content">
      <h1>hi, i'm jordan</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove landing class height and add landing-content class height to 100%. When you add landing class height to 100vh, It covers 100vh height. But logo class already covers some height. so it overflows.

```
.landing {
  background: url(bg.svg);
}

.landing-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/alimurrazi/36svho08/1/

Answer (score 0):

Since `.app` has the default `display: block`, `.logo` takes up however much space it needs, then `.landing` goes underneath, taking up *an additional* 100vh, so that you need to scroll to view its full content.

The solution here is either to simply add `overflow-y: hidden` to `.app`, but that still leaves your text off center by a bit. Another solution would be to give `.app` `display: flex`, and using flexbox to distribute the space as needed.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.landing {
  background: url(bg.svg);
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.landing-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.landing-content h1 {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

.app {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  
  <div class="logo">
     <h1>logo</h1>
  </div>
      
  <div class="landing">
    <div class="landing-content">
      <h1>hi, i'm jordan</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the .app class as follow.

```
.app {
  background-color: black;
  height: auto;
  color: white;
}
```